# How to Count the rows based on another Column in a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, count, sum

I have 7 columns in these three are ReadOnly Fields and based on Consumable Name i want to Sum the Quantity Issued Field.

i want to Sum the **Quantity Issued based on the Consumable Name and the total sum is compared to the Quantity Required**  They are so many consumable Names. My question How to calculate the **Quantity Issued** Column based on **Consumable Name**.
I tried and finally i got the answer it is something logically i am failed to explain it.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I am searching for that how to sum the values in a column based on another column.

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a List of strings with all rows of column 'Consumable Name'. Fill with names.

2)Create a List of integers equal to the number of items in the above List. Fill with quantities.

3)Create a List of distinct strings from (1).

4)Create a List of integers equal to the number of items in (3).

5)Step into each distinct element and get the related matching 'Consumable Name' and add quantities.

6)Similar steps you can follow if you wish to compare or check other columns.

You can refer to the below code:

```
    public void getQuantity()
    {
        List<string> consumbleNames = new List<string>();
        List<int> quantity = new List<int>();

        //Cells[5] refer to 6th column : Quantity issued: you can use column name too
        for (int i = 0; i < yourDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            consumbleNames.Add(yourDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            quantity.Add((int)Convert.ToInt32(yourDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()));
        }

        List<string> distinctNames = new List<string>(consumbleNames.Distinct());
        List<int> quantityRelated = new List<int>(distinctNames.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < distinctNames.Count; i++)
        {
            quantityRelated.Add(new int());

            for (int j = 0; j < consumbleNames.Count; j++)
            {
                if (consumbleNames[j].Equals(distinctNames[i]))
                {
                    quantityRelated[i] += quantity[j];
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (int t in quantityRelated)
        {
            /* quantity corresponds to the each distinct item */
        }
    }
```